# Bluetooth receive file in c

Tags: c, bluetooth, obex

I'm developing a bluetooth application in c using bluez and I want to send and receive file
anyone have some code example that I can use?
tnx

Comment: How far did you get? Where are you stuck?

Comment: which profile are you planning on using in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android , there is a bluetooth chat application over SPP which is a good starting point
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: I`m not using android, i`m using Ubuntu10.10